# Spell check for whole project strings?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ios8

Is there some kind of way to spell check all the strings used in an iOS project? Is there maybe already an open source project for this?

Comment: Open all of your `strings` files in TextEdit.

Comment: what do u need to check? Grammar mistakes or program syntax errors? Be more precise.

Comment: @DariusMiliauskas The question clearly asks about spell checking all of the strings.

Comment: I need to check _everything_. All Strings defined in @"", Strings lying in .strings-files etc. It only needs to be checked once for every release or so, not everytime someone´s typing.

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately, Xcode doesn't provide a feature to search for all spelling mistakes across the project. The only way to do it in Xcode is to open all files one by one and use the option of `Edit -> Format -> Spelling and Grammar -> Check Document Now`.

Answer (score -2):

Spelling can be checked in "X Code" the following way:

```
Edit -> Format -> Spelling and Grammar -> Check Document Now
```

However, "X Code" is not a text editor, so, you can check as well using other text editors or internet translators (e. g. Google translator).

Comment: It's not what was asked in question. The option described only checks the currently open file. The author of the question wanted to find all spelling mistakes across the project, not only in a single file.